# pyqt - Automatically update widget on user input

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Total pyqt novice here. Trying to automatically modify the widget to display different options when user selects certain option in combobox 2. IE if user selects 'Cliff Erosion' or 'Dune Erosion', I want the widget to refresh with additional comboboxes. Likewise, if they select back to 'Rising Tides' or 'Coastal Flooding' I'd like the widget to go back to original call. How do I refresh the widget?

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


# Create window
class Window(QWidget):

    #This block adds features into the window init
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Monterey Bay Sea Level Rise')
        self.resize(300, 240)
        self.addWidgets1()


    def addWidgets1(self):


        #Add drop-down list for selecting forecast year
        self.year_lbl = QLabel("1. Select Forecast Year", self)
        self.year_lbl.move(5,0)
        year = QComboBox(self)
        year.addItem('2030')
        year.addItem('2060')
        year.addItem('2100')
        year.move(5,20)

        #Add drop-down list for selecting hazard
        self.hazard_lbl = QLabel("2. Select Coastal Hazard", self)
        self.hazard_lbl.move(5,50)
        hazard = QComboBox(self)
        hazard.addItem('Rising Tides')
        hazard.addItem('Coastal Storm Flooding')
        hazard.addItem('Cliff Erosion')
        hazard.addItem('Dune Erosion')
        hazard.activated[str].connect(self.addWidget2) 
        hazard.move(5,70)

        #Add drop-down list for inputing model intensity (s1,s2,s3)
        self.intensity_lbl = QLabel("3. Select Intensity", self)
        self.intensity_lbl.move(5,100)
        intensity = QComboBox(self)
        intensity.addItem('Low')
        intensity.addItem('Mid')
        intensity.addItem('High') 
        intensity.move(5,120)


    def addWidget2(self,text):
        #if hazard is cliff erosion or dune erosion we want to update the widget
        #... to include wstorm,long_term AND no_change,stormier

        if text == 'Cliff Erosion' or text == 'Dune Erosion':
            print 'Hi'

            self.type_lbl = QLabel("3. Select type of changes", self)
            self.type_lbl.move(5,150)
            types = QComboBox(self)
            types.addItem('Long-term')
            types.addItem('Storm induced')
            types.move(5,180)

            self.storm_lbl = QLabel("4. Select for stormier", self)
            self.storm_lbl.move(5,150)
            storm = QComboBox(self)
            storm.addItem('No Change')
            storm.addItem('Stormier')
            storm.move(5,180)       


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    #window.resize(100, 60)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way of adding widgets to a Qt application is to use [layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html). They will calculate the preferred size and location of your widgets and update this when needed, e.g. when widgets are added or when the window is resized (note what happens when you make your window smaller during execution and compare it with my solution below). I'm certain that it's possible to do all the moving and resizing yourself, but QLayouts are really the way to go and I strongly recommend you use them too.

There are a few types of QLayouts but in your case I would use a QFormLayout. To my surprise the QFormLayout does have an `addRow` method but no corresponding `removeRow`. However I find that just showing/hiding the combo boxes when needed does the trick as well. I've adapted your example below.

Finally, even just showing or hiding the last two combo boxes will cause the layout to slightly move the first three. This is caused by the fact that the 4th label is the longest of them all. I find that annoying. Perhaps a better solution is to enable/disable the combo boxes when needed. This has the additional benefit of showing the user that these options even exist. See also the code below. A second alternative may be to use a QGridLayout (instead of a QFormLayout) and use `setColumnMinimumWidth` to set the first column to a size that will hold all possible labels.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui 

# Create window
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    #This block adds features into the window init
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Monterey Bay Sea Level Rise')
        self.resize(300, 240)
        self.addWidgets1()

    def addWidgets1(self):

        self.layout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        #Add drop-down list for selecting forecast year

        # You don't need to set to parent of the widgets to self anymore, the
        # layout will set the parent automatically when you add the widgets
        self.year_lbl = QtGui.QLabel("1. Select Forecast Year")
        # self.year_lbl.move(5,0) # Can be removed. The layout takes care of it.
        year = QtGui.QComboBox()
        year.addItem('2030')
        year.addItem('2060')
        year.addItem('2100')
        self.layout.addRow(self.year_lbl, year)        

        #Add drop-down list for selecting hazard
        self.hazard_lbl = QtGui.QLabel("2. Select Coastal Hazard")
        self.hazard = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.hazard.addItem('Rising Tides')
        self.hazard.addItem('Coastal Storm Flooding')
        self.hazard.addItem('Cliff Erosion')
        self.hazard.addItem('Dune Erosion')
        self.hazard.activated[str].connect(self.updateComboboxes) 
        self.layout.addRow(self.hazard_lbl, self.hazard)        

        #Add drop-down list for inputing model intensity (s1,s2,s3)
        self.intensity_lbl = QtGui.QLabel("3. Select Intensity")
        intensity = QtGui.QComboBox()
        intensity.addItem('Low')
        intensity.addItem('Mid')
        intensity.addItem('High') 
        self.layout.addRow(self.intensity_lbl, intensity)        

        self.types_lbl = QtGui.QLabel("3. Select type of changes")
        self.types = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.types.addItem('Long-term')
        self.types.addItem('Storm induced')
        self.layout.addRow(self.types_lbl, self.types)        

        self.storm_lbl = QtGui.QLabel("4. Select for stormier")
        self.storm = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.storm.addItem('No Change')
        self.storm.addItem('Stormier')
        self.layout.addRow(self.storm_lbl, self.storm)        

        # show initial state
        self.updateComboboxes() 


    def updateComboboxes(self, text=None):
        #if hazard is cliff erosion or dune erosion we want to update the widget
        #... to include wstorm,long_term AND no_change,stormier

        if text is None:
            text = self.hazard.currentText()

        usable = (text == 'Cliff Erosion' or text == 'Dune Erosion')

        if True: # change to False to use enabling/disabling widgets
            # May cause other widgets to be relocated
            self.types_lbl.setVisible(usable)
            self.types.setVisible(usable)
            self.storm_lbl.setVisible(usable)
            self.storm.setVisible(usable)
        else:
            # This option doesn't relocate widgets
            # Also may give additional clue to the uses that this exsits
            self.types_lbl.setEnabled(usable)
            self.types.setEnabled(usable)
            self.storm_lbl.setEnabled(usable)
            self.storm.setEnabled(usable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    #window.resize(100, 60)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```